# How can you use LINQ to cast from a collection of base class objects to a filtered list of their respective subclasses?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

We have several different data types that all share a particular base class.  We also have a `List<BaseClass>` that contains a random collection of those subclass objects in no particular order.

Using Linq/Lambda expressions, we're trying to extract each individual subclass type, ordered by a property of that specific subclass, then store it in a strongly-typed value of `List<SubclassType>`

Here's what I'm currently doing, but not being a LINQ expert, I have a feeling there's a much easier way to achieve this. (I'm getting the feeling my Where and Select are somehow redundant and cause more-than-needed passes over the collection, but I could be wrong.)

```
class baseItem{}

class subItemX : baseItem
{
    public int XSortValue{ get; set; }
}

class subItemY : baseItem
{
    public int YSortValue{ get; set; }
}

List<MyBaseClass> allItems = GetAllItems(); // Random collection of subclass objects.

// Is there an easier/less verbose way to achieve these two?
List<SubItemX> xItemsOnly = allItems
    .Where(baseItem => baseItem is SubItemX)
    .Select(baseItem => baseItem as SubItemX)
    .OrderBy(subItemX => subItemX.XSortValue)
    .ToList();

List<SubItemY> yItemsOnly = allItems
    .Where(baseItem => baseItem is SubItemY)
    .Select(baseItem => baseItem as SubItemY)
    .OrderBy(subItemY => subItemY.YSortValue)
    .ToList();
```

However, I have a feeling I've made these much more complicated than they need to be.  Is this the most efficient way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to utilize `OfType<T>` to filter your mixed sequence and extract your results as the desired type.

```
var xItemsOnly = allItems.OfType<SubItemX>().OrderBy(s => s.XSortValue).ToList();
```

A similar method that you may wish to explore is `Cast<T>` that instead of filtering and converting, simply converts (and throws if a conversion does not succeed). Use this if you *know* all of the items in a sequence of a lesser derived type are actually of the more derived type. Otherwise, if your intent is to filter a possibly-mixed sequence, use the `OfType<T>` method previously displayed (and that is certainly what you would do, given your question).

Comment: Quick question though... can you filter right at cast-time on a property of the subclass, or do you have to add a separate `Where` clause afterwards causing another pass over the results?  Our real-world use-case is actually that we only want certain SubItemX objects that have a particular property set. (e.g. only SubItemX objects with subItemX.foo == 1 kinda thing.)

Comment: Just as you can use OrderBy, you could also apply a Where or any other applicable extension method on the resulting sequence from OfType. Remember that this is lazy in evaluation, the entire sequence does not need to be filtered through OfType before the Where filter also starts taking effect. Obviously by the time OrderBy has to be evaluated, it will need to have completed all of the filtering, but OfType and Where will chain together nicely.

Comment: Picture it like "take the first item from allItems. Is it a SubItemX? Good. Now does item.foo equal 1? Great, I want it. Now look at the second item from allItems. [repeat]." Make sense? I'm commenting because I was interpreting your question as you weren't sure if *all* of the sequence is filtered through OfType, and only then do *all* of those results pass through Where. That is not how it would be achieved, assuming you're using the standard Linq-to-Objects provider.

Comment: Oh, ok, good!  I thought each step executed in full as it went, meaning if you (were dumb and) chained Where statements together, then you would take multiple passes over the results.  Jooc... would this have worked?  var filteredXItems = allItems.Where(item => (item is SubItemX) && (((SubItemX)item).foo == 1) ).ToList<SubItemX>(); ?  That clearly is a single pass (without the ordering, of course.)

Comment: Yes, and it would be *effectively* the same as allItems.Where(onePredicate).Where(anotherPredicate).Where(thirdPredicate).(...) and you can continue to chain them. These type of methods yield their results one at a time to the next method, so you're not walking the sequence multiple times as you apply these filters when the query is evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for the info! :)  Voted and accepted!  Again, jooc, where did you get the info on the internals of this?  Again, just reading it it looks like each statement completes over the entire list before moving on, but you've clearly shown that isn't the case (except obviously for OrderBy).  Is there some sort of LINQ profiler that we can use (like we can with SQL statements?)

Comment: I just checked, and the documentation certainly does not appear to be quite as explicit on this as you might like. However, Linq is generally designed to use deferred execution as much as possible, and to not force more evaluations than required. You can easily use stream results one-by-one from one method to another using standard C# language tools, and the Linq methods also achieve that when appropriate.

Comment: If you are more interested in *approximations* of Linq method implementations, you can search for Jon Skeet's "Edulinq" blog series where he reimplemented Linq-to-Objects from scratch.

Comment: Well I can always manually profile. And thanks for the Skeet ref too. Should be fun to read and a big help! Thanks again!

Comment: Last thing, I would be remissed if I didn't point out that if you put your breakpoints in the right places, you could observe the yielding of items from one method to another in your debugger. I don't know why I didn't point that out before.